# VScode James yu latex workshop custom recipe not using bibtex when setting a output folder

Tags: vscode

I wanted to output pdfs and their auxiliary files into an output folder. It works normally for normal builds and when using recipes it does output into the output folder

```
"latex-workshop.latex.outDir": ".\\out\\",
"latex-workshop.latex.tools":[
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "command": "pdflatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "-aux-directory=out",
                "-output-directory=out",
                "%DOC%"
            ]
        },
    ],
```

However, whenever I use the recipe `pdflatex > bibtex > pdflatex > pdflatex`, it does not add citations at all:

[image].

However, when I remove the arguments, it outputs into my main folder instead of the output folder it adds the citations. I still can not figure out why it does that or how to fix it.